# Can I use the Entity Framework when I already have my Model and database?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework-5

In my working WPF application I already have my model and sqlce database.
However now I use normal parameterized queries to retrieve, update or delete my data.

Can I still use the Entity Framework for this or is it too late? My model implements INotifyChangedProperty (MVVM application).

An example of the insert method in my AddressModel as is now. I would like to change this using the Entity Framework.

```
    public int InsertNewAddress(bool isnew)
{
  IsNew = isnew;
  try
  {
    ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Id", Value = Id, DbType = DbType.Guid, Size = 16, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Street", Value = Street, DbType = DbType.String, Size = 50, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Number", Value = Number, DbType = DbType.String, Size = 10, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Bus", Value = DBNull.Value, DbType = DbType.String, Size = 5, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@ZipCode", Value = Zipcode, DbType = DbType.String, Size = 10, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@City", Value = City, DbType = DbType.String, Size = 50, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Created", Value = DateTime.Now, DbType = DbType.DateTime, Size = 23, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Modified", Value = DateTime.Now, DbType = DbType.DateTime, Size = 23, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
    paramList.Add(new SqlCeParameter() { ParameterName = "@Country", Value = Country, DbType = DbType.String, Size = 50, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (IsNew) // new address, insert
    {
      sb.Append("INSERT INTO [RF_Address] ");
      sb.Append("([Id],[Street],[Number],[Bus],[ZipCode],[City] ,[DateCreated],[DateModified], [Country]) ");
      sb.Append("VALUES ");
      sb.Append("(@Id, @Street, @Number, @Bus, @ZipCode, @City, @Created, @Modified, @Country)");
    }
    else
    {
      sb.Append("UPDATE  [RF_Address] ");
      sb.Append("SET ");
      sb.Append("[Street] = @Street, [Number] = @Number, [Bus] = @Bus, [ZipCode] = @ZipCode, [City] = @City, ");
      sb.Append("[DateModified] = @Modified,  [Country] = @Country ");
      sb.Append("WHERE [Id] = @Id");
    }

    int result = SqlCeHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sb.ToString(), paramList);
    if (result != 1)
      throw new CustomException("Insert address failed!");

    return result;
  }
  catch (CustomException appEx)
  {
    throw new CustomException(appEx.Message, appEx);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception("Error InsertNewAddress: " + ex.Message, ex);
  }
}
```

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Entity Framework has three workflows: `Database First`, `Model First` and `Code First`, so among the three you can use `Database First`

- [Entity Framework Database First (*with tutorial*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx)
- [Which workflow should I use?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907)

Comment: Thx for the fast reply. That will create new models if I understand correctly? My application is a WPF MVVM application, so my model implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Can I do this with the models generated from the Entity Framework to?

Comment: yes, you will be force to migrate your codes since you want to use `EF`.

Comment: I'll look at it in the weekend.. Just to see if I understand your answer correct, the EF will create new models and I can make the properties INotifyPropertyChanged?